# Drupal account creation when Drupal account exists

Tags: drupal, account-creation

We're seeing a fairly frequent problem where a user tries to create an account when they already have an account. The flow from that point is then: CiviCRM creates a contact record for them with the "Create Drupal User" tag, the Drupal rule to create the Drupal account kicks in presumably, but because they already have a Drupal account nothing happens. The user does not get any notification that they have an account already, they don't get an email, nothing.

So their next step is to do that like 5 more times (creating that many more contact record dupes), and then ask for help.  I know we can use matching rules to prevent the dupes, but is there an established way to alert the user - probably via email - that the account already exists and they just need to reset their email?

Comment: Are you using the CMS User extension? If so, doesn't it create an Activity or something when it tries and fails - and if so you could use CiviRules to trigger an email from that

Comment: Confirmed that using CMS User extension https://github.com/Skvare/com.skvare.cmsuser if a user already exists then an Activity of type "User Account Creation" with Subject "Failed to create User <username> (user already exist)" and hence CiviRules should be able to pick up on that and fire off an email (think an extra extension is needed for sending emails  https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api

Comment: if the above is the answer then i will convert this thread to an Answer

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - wow, I had no idea. I do have that extension installed, and I have some of those Activities, but none recently. So it sounds like something is missing/broken, but this definitely give me a direction to look in, thanks!

Comment: I tested, and the extension doesn't seem to be adding activities for success or failure - the last such activities were from 2021. Not sure why that might be! I also now recall why we stopped using the matching functionality - it makes it so that anyone who knows the email can submit the form and change the contact details for that contact. Not great!

Comment: We are working around that by adding a new feature (i hope) to webform_civicrm so you can a/ specify that if no match exists then a new contact is NOT created and then b/ the webform sends the existing contact an email with checksum to go to a second form to do their updates - so kind of like a self-service checksum system